# using supertabs in my ionic dashboard page my tab pages are all loading when I enter the dashboard page. I expected them to load only when requested

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am building an ionic 5 app that uses supertabs. I have five supertabs (A,B,C,D,E). In each tabPage.ts I use ngOnInit to initialize variables for the task of each tab. My problem is I noticed that the ngOnInit methods in each tab get executed before I selected. This I suspect is happening because all the supertab pages are loaded at the same time ..not just the default tab. Is this the expected behavior??. I am using lazy load to load the pages. I have also checked the PreLoadStrategy to no effect.
This is what my .html looks like:

```
<!-- <app-header [title]='title'></app-header> -->
<ion-header>
   <ion-toolbar *ngIf="!searchbar" color="orange">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons >
    <ion-title color="light"><b>Dashboard</b></ion-title>
    <!-- <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-icon color="light" size="large" name="search-sharp" (click)="searchbar = true"></ion-icon>
    </ion-buttons> -->
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-icon color="light" (click)="openProfile()" size="large" name="person-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-toolbar *ngIf="searchbar">
    <ion-searchbar placeholder="Search..."
     (ionCancel)="searchbar = false" [debounce]="250" showCancelButton="always"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<super-tabs activeTabIndex="1" [config]="{ debug: true, sideMenu: 'left', allowElementScroll: true, nativeSmoothScroll: true }">
  <super-tabs-toolbar color="primary" slot="top">
    <super-tab-button>
      <ion-label color="light">A</ion-label>
    </super-tab-button>
    <super-tab-button>
      <ion-label color="light">B</ion-label>
    </super-tab-button>
    <super-tab-button>
      <ion-label color="light">C</ion-label>
    </super-tab-button>
    <super-tab-button>
      <ion-label color="light">D</ion-label>
    </super-tab-button>
    <super-tab-button>
      <ion-label color="light">E</ion-label>
    </super-tab-button>
  </super-tabs-toolbar>

  <super-tabs-container autoScrollTop>
    <super-tab>
      <ion-nav [root]="a"></ion-nav>
    </super-tab>
    <super-tab>
      <ion-nav [root]="b"></ion-nav>
    </super-tab>
    <super-tab>
      <ion-nav [root]="c"></ion-nav>
    </super-tab>
    <super-tab>
      <ion-nav [root]="d"></ion-nav>
    </super-tab>
    <super-tab>
      <ion-nav [root]="e"></ion-nav>
    </super-tab>
  </super-tabs-container>
</super-tabs>
```

Comment: You should ask this question on the related GitHub repository: https://github.com/zyra/ionic-super-tabs 
It looks like there is already an open bug related to your issue: https://github.com/zyra/ionic-super-tabs/issues/466

Comment: @BenjaminLüscher ...thanks for the link...but the problem is not quite the same and no one has responded since March 21. I wouldn't recommend to someone looking for answers